# operator norm respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

I come up with this problem

Let
$$T= \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 10 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix} $$

1. Show that $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} ||T^n||^{1/n}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
2. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a basis $B$
   of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which
   $$ ||T||_{B}< \frac{1}{2} + \epsilon $$
   where $||T||_B$ is the uniform norm of $T$ corresponding to Euclidean $B-norm$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
3. Show that for any basis $B$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$
   $$ ||T||_{B} > \frac{1}{2}. $$

I know there is a generalization of this problem called [Gelfand's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius), but in this case it should be proven with just the knowledge of norms and the operator norm.

For 1, $T$ can be written as $T=S+N$ where
$$ S= \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 &0 \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix} \quad N= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &0 \\ 10 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
so that $T^n=S^n+nS^{k-1}N$ and so $||T^n||$ can be reduced to a usual limit of numbers, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, I think it can be used $||T^n||^{1/n}\leq ||T||$, just not sure how. Also what's the operator norm in some basis? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Kindly define the "uniform" norm with respect to a basis $B$. Also the norm without subscript is the usual matrix norm, I believe?

Comment: The text doesn't define that $||T||_{B}$ is and I don't know either and in this case $||T||=\max_{|x| \leq 1} ||Tx||$.  Hope answered correctly.

Comment: There is a problem with parts $2$ and $3$, the inequalities don't seem right.

Comment: what do you mean? The problem can be found in page 87, exercise  5, from Hirsch and Smale's book ( https://www.elsevier.com/books/differential-equations-dynamical-systems-and-linear-algebra/hirsch/978-0-12-349550-1)